# SQL Query- NOT exists Not working

Tags: sql, mariadb, not-exists

```
select *
from text_mining
where  NOT EXISTS (select 1 from history
                  where text_mining.Noun = history.Noun
                    and text_mining.Adjective = history.Adjective)
```

can someone tell me what is wrong with this this are my errors Thanks

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT" at position 35)
>   Unrecognized keyword. (near "EXISTS" at position 39)
>   Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 46)

Comment: if I use Exists it works but when I add not, it wont

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS and version

Comment: 10.1.16-MariaDB, I am using Xampp, PHPMyadmin @McNets

Comment: Your query should work.  I'm guessing you have an invisible character around the `NOT`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff how can i remove it? i tried to retype it still wont work :3

Comment: I am able to run it without the NOT, 
select * from text_mining a where EXISTS (select 1 from history b where a.Noun = b.Noun and a.Adjective = b.Adjective)

Comment: Have you tried checking your DB's documentation for `NOT EXISTS`? Maybe it'll have a changelog/version log that will be helpful.

Comment: I found a way out of it, instead of using not I used !EXISTS
select *
from text_mining
where  !EXISTS (select 1 from history
                  where text_mining.Noun = history.Noun
                    and text_mining.Adjective = history.Adjective)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM history a
WHERE !EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM text_mining b 
WHERE a.Noun = b.Noun AND a.Adjective = b.Adjective)
```

Used `!EXISTS` instead of `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

Position 35 mean the space between the key word 'NOT'and ÉXISTS'; your query should work, try to delete hiden character in position 35;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.*
    FROM  text_mining AS t
    LEFT JOIN  history AS h USING(Nown, Adjective)
    WHERE  h.id IS NULL
```

`history` should have `INDEX(Noun, Adjective)` in either order.